# Webpack Image Path

Tags: wordpress, webpack, node-modules, webpack-style-loader

I coded my site using Webpack.  Everything works except the image's path.  I'm used to write `../img/test.png` for it work.  I've researched other questions but none work.

My files are organized inside the `dist` folder of the wordpress theme.

Here's my `webpack.config.js` :

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: [
        './src/index.js'
    ],
    devtool: "source-map", // any "source-map"-like devtool is possible
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        compress: true,
        port: 9000
    },
    module:{
        rules:[
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['env']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test:/\.(s*)css$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: "style-loader", options: {
                        sourceMap: true
                    }
                }, {
                    loader: "css-loader", options: {
                        sourceMap: true
                    }
                }, {
                    loader: "resolve-url-loader", //resolve-url-loader needs to come *BEFORE* sass-loader
                    options: {
                      sourceMap: true
                    }
                },{
                    loader: "sass-loader", options: {
                        sourceMap: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {from:'assets/images',to:'images'} 
        ])
    ],
    watch: true,
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),  
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
};
```

I've tried other url-loaders but nothing seems to work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  The public and output path were the most important things I had to learn.  Since this was with Wordpress, the other answers weren't sufficient.  The new config looks like:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: [
        './src/index.js'
    ],
    devtool: "source-map", // any "source-map"-like devtool is possible
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        compress: true,
        port: 9000
    },
    module:{
        rules:[
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['env']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/,
                use: [
                  {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        outputPath: 'images',
                        publicPath: 'wp-content/themes/{{ THEME NAME }}/dist/images',
                    },
                  },
                ],
            },
            {
                test:/\.(s*)css$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: "style-loader", options: {
                        sourceMap: true
                    }
                }, {
                    loader: "css-loader", options: {
                        sourceMap: true
                    }
                }, {
                    loader: "sass-loader", options: {
                        sourceMap: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    },
    watch: true,
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),  
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
};
```

Hope this helps for anyone who is working through this.